Bashscript failure with divided calculations
I have a problem with my pocket calculator which is written in polish notation, it can calculate everything up to part by part which results in coma numbers, how can I solve this problem?

#!/bin/bash

calculate() {
    num1=$1
    num2=$2
    operator=$3

    if [ "$operator" = "+" ]; then
        echo $(($num1 + $num2))
    elif [ "$operator" = "-" ]; then
        echo $(($num1 - $num2))
    elif [ "$operator" = "x" ]; then
        echo $(($num1 * $num2))
    elif [ "$operator" = "/" ]; then
        echo $(($num1 / $num2))
    else
        echo "This is not a correct calculation!"
    fi
}

while true; do
    read -p "What is your calculation? (e.g. 7 3 +, -, x, / or 'q' to finish): " num1 num2 operator

    if [[ $num1 = "q" || $num2 = "q" || $operator = "q" ]]; then
        echo "Script is terminated..."
        break
    fi

    result=$(calculate $num1 $num2 $operator)
    echo "Result: $result"
done


Bash doesn't support floating point numbers. Use an external tool like bc.

I don't know what kind of precision you need for decimals, but if you are happy with the usual floating point arithmetic, consider writing the script in zsh (which can do floats). If you need real "decimal" arithmetic (instead of floats), I suggest using a programming language which has support for this (for instance bc, as choroba suggested, or Ruby, which has the data type BigDecimal ).

@user1934428 it was just a school assignment, which finally had to be handed in with the file extension sh, that's why i was looking for solutions, but it's cleared up, thanks
